# How can i use form_for so as to get a hidden_field value using params in controller#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, parameters, form-for

I need your help.I need get `current_user.id` (I use Devise gem) to `articles#create`. I wanna pass it  by means `form_for` and  `hidden field`. I've written:

```
<%= form_for :article, url: articles_path do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :text %><br/>
    <%= f.text_area :text %>
  </p>

  <p>
 # It's here
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id %>
```

I've got:

```
<input type="hidden" name="article[user_id]" id="article_user_id"/>
```

but I need:

```
<input type="hidden" name="article[user_id]" id="article_user_id" value="2"/>
```

I've written this html code in **new.html.erb**

```
<input type="hidden" name="article[user_id]" id="article_user_id" value="<%= current_user.id%>"/>
```

and Active Record saved object to database.I inspect `params` and I don't see my hidden value.
 I wanna ask you two question:
1. How can I write `hidden_field` in `form_for`?
2. How can I get to articles#create this hidden value by means `params`?

Comment: try this, <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, current_user.id %> OR <%= hidden_field_tag :user_id, current_user.id %>

Comment: Thank you,second version is work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
```

And then in your controller (usually in `article_params`) make sure that you permit the user_id parameter.

```
def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:user_id, :title, ...)
end
```

A better way to do this would be setting it server-side, because the hidden field could be manipulated.. as an example:

```
def create
  @article = current_user.articles.new(article_params)
  if @article.save
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: You can click the check in my answer to say that this was the answer and so close this question.

Comment: Where can I click?

Comment: You already did (a check looking like: √ in the upper left corner)

Answer (score 0):

With devise, for the current signed-in user, `current_` helper is available. Assuming your user model is 'user'. Try

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'user_id', current_user.user_id %>
```